# 3d график по функции.C#

Tags: c#, 3d

Необходимо считывая значения x,y c DataGried построить 3D график z=f(x,y)
Не могу разобраться как реализовать 3D в chart???Помогите кому не сложно, понимаю что вопрос возможно для начинающего

Answer (score 3):

Если вы используете **[System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart(v=vs.110).aspx)** - обычный WinForms Chart, то никак. Он не умеет 3D от слова совсем.

При всей внешней похожести, это не эквивалент графиков из Excel. Все что он умеет - это плоские (2D) графики.

Полный список типов графиков можно посмотреть в перечислении **[SeriesChartType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.seriescharttype(v=vs.110).aspx)**

Для 3D графиков вроде поверхностей, придется искать сторонние компоненты, но с этим, к сожалению помочь не могу. Тут несколько раз упоминался ZedGraph, но он, судя по **[описанию](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/)**, тоже не умеет 3D. Еще как вариант сделать свой контрол для построения графиков, но это весьма сложная и трудоемкая работа.

UPD:

Нашел в **[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489205.aspx)** пример, как получить 3d-представление плоского графика. Это не отменяет всего выше сказанного, т.к. не решает проблему построения поверхностей и прочих объемных графиков.